# Pentaho slow reporting

Tags: pentaho, business-intelligence

have been working on a projet about data integration, analysing and reporting using Pentaho. So at last, I needed to do some reporting using Pentaho report designer, weekly. The problem that is our data is so big (about 4M/day), so the reporting platform was too slow and we can't do any other queries from tables in use, until we kill the process. Is there any solution to this ? A reporting tool or platform that we can use instead of Pentaho tool without having to change the whole thing and get from the first ETL steps.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean 4M records/day.

That’s not particularly big for reporting, but the devil is in the details. You may need to tweak your db structure and analyze the various queries at play.

As you describe it, there isn’t much info to go with to give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: To be more specific :
The first problem is that the multidimensional analytic tool in pentaho has a limit of 1000 records that I can manipulate, so is there any other free tool to be able to analyse more lines ? 
The second problem is, I am using the connection between reporting designer and oracle db, so I acces db directly, and that what causes less performance and stuff.
I hope I made some sens now !